# How to get the last but one row id in the table

Tags: php, html

How can get the last but one row id in my dynamic HTML Table

```
<table>
 <tr id='1'>...</tr>
 <tr id='2'>...</tr>
 <tr id='3'>...</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the "last but one" row? and in what sense do you want to *get* it? your question is close to the definition of "unclear", please provide more detail

Comment: actually in dynamic table first and second row coming from the data base table and i added to third row manually.i want dynamic  last <tr> id. which means id =2, but i don't how many rows in my data base table.is it possible?